# Parameter pack-type of constructor does not work with vector.emplace_back

Tags: c++

I have my own (math)vector type and I want to push back a bunch of these into a (c++)vector. However, the code does not work in latest Visual Studio 2017 RC. It works with the HEAD versions of GCC and Clang (according to Wandbox). Is this a Visual Studio bug?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

template<typename WantedType, typename... Args>
constexpr bool helper_function()
{
  return (std::is_same_v<WantedType, Args> && ... && true);
}


template <typename Type, std::size_t dim>
struct VecND {

  VecND() = default;

  template <typename ...Args, std::enable_if_t<(helper_function<Type, Args...>()) >* = nullptr>
  explicit VecND(Args&&... args) : m_array{ {std::forward<Args>(args)...} }
  {
  }

  std::array<Type, dim> m_array{};
};



int main()
{

  using Vec2D = VecND<double, 2>;
  std::vector< Vec2D > my_vec;

  my_vec.emplace_back(3.4, 21.4);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a bunch of error messages (as one does when using templates), but I think the relevant one is:

> xmemory0(881): error C2661: 'VecND::VecND': no overloaded
>   function takes 2 arguments

Comment: Add `/std:c++latest` to the compiler options.

Comment: @user657267 Doesn't fix it. As long as `helper_function` is templated, it doesn't work. If it's not templated, it works. https://godbolt.org/z/RGtPr3

Comment: It works for me with 19.15.26732.1

Comment: It compiles without a warning with VS2017 15.8.9.

The only project options I changed from the default was turning off using precompiled headers and setting the language to /std:c++17.

Comment: Right, MSVC already doesn't like the parameter pack expansion (on `&&`) itself in my link.

Comment: On Godbolt selecting MSVC Pre 2018 also seems to work, there seem to be a few bugs related to fold expressions on the VS developer community, the RTW 2017 version on Goldbolt must simply be too old.

Comment: [OT]: You might use `std::index_sequence` in your class parameter to avoid template constructor, something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a20b109b05048a93).

Comment: @Jarod42, neat trick, thanks.